# Can I group_by then separate into columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot-table

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| number  | type  |   price  |
+---------+-------+----------+
|    1    |   A   |   7.00   | 
|    1    |   B   |   3.00   | 
|    2    |   A   |   1.00   | 
|    2    |   B   |   2.00   | 
|    3    |   A   |   6.00   | 
|    3    |   B   |   9.00   |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

If I have a table like the example table above. Is it possible to run a query that would a result in a table like the below example in mysql?

```
+---------+---------+----------+
| number  |    A    |     B    |
+---------+---------+----------+
|    1    |   7.00  |   3.00   | 
|    2    |   1.00  |   2.00   | 
|    3    |   6.00  |   9.00   | 
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Search for pivot table.

Comment: You need to use a pivot table: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks I'll have to read up on pivot tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select number,
       min(case when `type` = 'A' then price end) as A,
       min(case when `type` = 'B' then price end) as B
from your_table
group by number
```